# shift up-arrow doesn't highlight text emacs iterm2

Tags: emacs, terminal

I recently had help fixing `M-left` and so forth here: [emacs in terminal meta arrow keybindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867199/emacs-in-terminal-meta-arrow-keybindings), but am unable to fix `Shift-up` using a similar solution. When I try `shift-up` I get an error `<select> is undefined`. I've tried re-mapping it using:

```
(add-hook 'term-setup-hook                                                                                                                                                                         
'(lambda ()                                                                                                                                                                                      
 (define-key function-key-map "\e[1;9A" [M-up])                                                                                                                                                
 (define-key function-key-map "\e[1;9B" [M-down])                                                                                                                                              
 (define-key function-key-map "\e[1;9C" [M-right])                                                                                                                                             
 (define-key function-key-map "\e[1;2A" [S-up])                                                                                                                                                
 (define-key function-key-map "\e[1;9D" [M-left])))
```

But shift remains undefined. I also tried rebinding the key by setting it using the escape sequence returned from `cat` which is `^[[1;2A`. Oddly enough shift down does work. `shift-select-mode` is marked at `t` as well.

Comment: Do you have more information on this question?  Or have you solved it in the past year?

Answer (score 13):

This sounds like a trouble I had accessing a Ubuntu 12.04 machine via Putty, when END caused Emacs 23.3.1 to say `<select> is undefined`. That turned out to be an issue with the [terminfo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminfo) that lets programs use terminals in a device independent way.

Based on this [2008 bug report discussion](http://www.archivum.info/bug-gnu-emacs@gnu.org/2008-12/00570/bug-1737-%28Vincent-Lefevre%29-The-End-key-doesn%27t-work-in-xterm-vt220.html), I solved my problem by adding the following to the top of my ~/.bashrc:

```
#so the END key will work correctly in Emacs over PuTTY
TERM=xterm-vt220
```

N.B., with either xterm-vt220 or the default xterm, `emacs -Q -nw` is getting `ESC [ 4 ~` when I press END, `ESC O A` for Up, and `ESC [ A` for Shift-Up.  (To see what keycodes Emacs is getting, press some buttons and then `C-h,l`.)  For the same keys in the same order, `cat` says `[4~`, `[A`, and `[OA`...so Up and Shift-Up are oddly reversed.

---

If you don't want to change your terminfo, see this discussion for a workaround
http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2011-05/msg00211.html

> You should be able to work around the issue with something like:
>
> `(define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;2A" [S-up])`
>
> And for this to take effect at the right time, you will have to use in your .emacs something like:
>
> `(if (equal "xterm" (tty-type))`
>        `(define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;2A" [S-up]))`

Answer (score 3):

Just to add more information about the solution:
https://github.com/arthurnn/dotfiles/blob/8d56f2419da9a4cb654d8941f379d6d5783bdb90/.emacs.d/init.d/setup-bindings.el#L3-L10 this should fix all the cases including emacsclient.
The last line is responsible for fixing the Shift-up when using emacsclient.