# Emacs move around split windows in a specified direction?

Tags: emacs

In Terminal Emacs (no mouse), I'm using split windows to work with multiple buffers at the same time. I'm finding moving between the split windows much more painful than how I do it in Vim. Reading the documentation it looks like I'm doing it correctly (<kbd>C-x o</kbd>), but that just cycles around the windows in a clockwise direction. If I move to an adjacent window to make a quick edit, I need to hit <kbd>C-x o</kbd> a few times before I'm back where I was. Sometimes I accidentally press it too many times in a hurry and have to cycle all the way back through the windows again.

Far from install yet-another-external-package, is there any way I can just either move directly to a window (by, say, a number), or at least cycle around the windows in the opposite direction?

In Vim <kbd>C-w C-w</kbd> is like <kbd>C-x o</kbd> in Emacs, but there's also <kbd>C-w ARROW</kbd> to move in a specified direction... something like that? :)

Comment: I know you said you don't want packages, but Evil uses the C-w bindings you know and love. :)

Comment: Have installed Evil, thanks. I'm enjoying it so far, because it doesn't interfere with Emacs commands as much as I thought it would.

Comment: @ChrisBarrett interestingly evil-mode seems to implement `C-w h/j/k/l`, but not the arrow-key variants of those. I guess I can easily map them myself.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Add this to your init file:

```
(windmove-default-keybindings)
```

Then you can use <kbd>SHIFT+*arrow*</kbd> to move to the next adjacent window in the specified direction.

You can specify a different modifier if you prefer, by passing an argument (defaults to `'shift`).

Or just bind whatever you like to these functions:

- `windmove-up`
- `windmove-down`
- `windmove-left`
- `windmove-right`

You can also add [FrameMove](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FrameMove) to the mix, to make this work transparently across multiple frames.

For numbered window navigation, there's [switch-window.el](https://github.com/dimitri/switch-window).

Comment: As OP states explicitly that Emacs is run in terminal, it's worth noting that `Shift+UP` doesn't work in xterm-based emulators, including gnome-terminal & terminator. See [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871745/shift-up-arrow-doesnt-highlight-text-emacs-iterm2) for more info.

Comment: Very good point; they'll likely need to specify their own bindings in that case. (Although xterm is one of the terminal emulators which *does* also facilitate extended key sequences, and I don't think the other two you mentioned are actually based on it :)

Comment: @phils, I should've picked words more accurately, I meant xterm-terminfo rather than xterm-the-emulator itself.

Comment: Bound to keys that work for my brain, this is totally awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Add this to your init file (e.g. `~/.emacs`):

```
(windmove-default-keybindings)
```

Then do <kbd>SHIFT+*arrow*</kbd> to move to the window in that direction.

Answer (score 3):

You can give a prefix argument to <kbd>C-x o</kbd> like this <kbd>C-u -1 C-x o</kbd>. This way you can go any number of windows forward or backward. Personally I think it's easier to create a special key for moving back one window. I have this in my .emacs:

```
(defun other-window-backward ()
  "Goto previous window"
  (interactive)
  (other-window -1))
(global-set-key (kbd "\C-x p") 'other-window-backward)
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that `other-window` accepts an argument like that, thanks. Nice and simple to customize with a mapping then :)

Answer (score 1):

I use the following to navigate to the next (same as <kbd>C-x o</kbd>), previous, first, and last window:

```
(defun my-previous-window ()
  "Previous window"
  (interactive)
  (other-window -1))
(global-set-key "\C-xp" 'my-previous-window)

(global-set-key "\C-xn" 'other-window)

(defun my-select-first-window ()
  (interactive)
  (select-window (frame-first-window)))

(defun my-select-last-window ()
  (interactive)
  (select-window (previous-window (frame-first-window))))

(global-set-key "\C-x<" 'my-select-first-window)
(global-set-key "\C-x>" 'my-select-last-window)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use window-jump, e.g.:

```
;; C-x <direction> to switch windows
(use-package window-jump
             :bind (("C-x <up>" . window-jump-up)
                    ("C-x <down>" . window-jump-down)
                    ("C-x <left>" . window-jump-left)
                    ("C-x <right>" . window-jump-right)))
```

For help with use-package, see https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package/blob/master/README.md.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completion, there is [window-numbering](https://github.com/nschum/window-numbering.el) and [ace-window](https://github.com/abo-abo/ace-window) too

Comment: I added this line to my .emacs but still can not move as expected. Something wrong? my version is 24.5

Answer (score -1):

I wrote an elisp module a while back to expand on windmove to make it a bit more useful: http://samograd.ca/stumpwm.el.  You can bind stumpwm-move-window-[left/right/up/down] to whatever keys you want and the windows will move in the correct direction, even into another another frame (tested with 2 frames).  There's also an stumpwm-interactive-resize-window for handy interactive window resizing using C-n/C-p/C-f/C-b with Return to end resizing.

Comment: The link is broken. Could you put this on the emacs wiki, or github, or some such?