# Emacs: Switch to specific window using multiple steps feature

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

I am aware that I can switch to the next window with the following commands:

C-x o (other-window)

However, in the emacs manual I found the following description:

> A numeric argument means to move several steps in the cyclic order of windows. A negative argument moves around the cycle in the opposite order.
> https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Other-Window.html

Unfortunately, I didn't find out how this actually works. When do I have to type the argument? After the "C-x o", i.e. "C-x o 3" if I want to jump three steps? This didn't work on my Mac.

I was quite surprised about this notion in the manual, because in all the posts that I read about the window switching capabilities of emacs, nobody ever mentioned this capability.

Comment: Unrelated to your actual question but you might want to check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607791/emacs-move-around-split-windows-in-a-specified-direction to learn about an alternative way to move around multiple windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is about the numeric prefix argument.

`C-u 3` followed by `C-x o` selects the 3rd "other" window in the cyclic order.
`C-u -3` selects the 3rd one in the other direction of cycling.

You can use just `C-3` or `M-3` for the first prefix, and just `C-- 3` or `M-- 3` for the second.

See the Emacs manual, node [Arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Arguments.html).