# Mouse inserts garbled text in emacs console mode

Tags: emacs, console, mouse

I'm using emacs 23.1.1 in console mode on a new analysis machine.  On other similar machines, I'm able to load up "emacs -nw" and do my thing, with the necessary option of highlighting text with my mouse and pasting it into another terminal window.  My understanding is that this is the only way to get text between different windows.

Anyway, on this new machine, when I left-click and hold with the mouse, rather than highlighting text, it just spews a bunch of garbled charcters, like:

> [M :, [M>-[M C/[M K0[M S1[M Z2[M `2

Google searches haven't turned up any question about a similar issue. I have no idea what's going on, particularly since, in similar environments on other machines (read: stuff just set up in its most basic fashion), I haven't had any problems.

I'm happy to supply further details, but I don't even know where to start.

Comment: try keeping shift key pressed while selecting the text

Comment: That seems to work.  Thanks!  Any ideas what setting might force me do it like that?

Comment: could you reproduce the behavior also without loading any plugin ? (try that by moving out your ~/.emacs.d dir and restarting emacs)

Comment: Ah, that does fix it.  I had installed the "xt-mouse.el" plugin (I thought in response this behavior), and the only other plugin was the color-theme.el.  

Not to derail the thread, but as a side note, the poking around began when I was trying to figure out how to get the console mode background to be white instead of the grey that was coming for "white" (the workaround was the change my $TERM to term-256color and choose "brightwhite" in the customization).  No idea if that's relevant.  Also , the END key gets me a "<select> is undefined" message -- again, maybe not relevant, but odd.

Comment: have you read this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871745/shift-up-arrow-doesnt-highlight-text-emacs-iterm2

Comment: Yeah, slightly different problem.  I just put a manual binding in my .emacs to force END to go to end of line.  I was mostly trying to suss out if there was some setting/dependency that had always been in the background of other environments that was missing here.  My usage of emacs has always been exceedingly vanilla (aside from preferring -nw mode).